# Shared Memory With Two Processes In C?

Tags: c, fork, shared-memory

I want to do the following:

Parent process creates a child process. Then the child process reads n int's from the user and store them in a shared memory. The parent process then displays them.

I reached the following:

```
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/ipc.h>
#include <sys/shm.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#define SHMSIZE 27
int main() {
   int shmid;
   int *shm;
   int *n;

   if(fork() == 0) {
      shmid = shmget(2009, SHMSIZE, 0);
      shm = shmat(shmid, 0, 0);
      n = shm;
      int i;
      for(i=0; i<5; i++) {
         printf("Enter number<%i>: ", i);
         scanf("%d", n++);
      }
      printf ("Child wrote <%d>\n",shm);
      shmdt(shm);
   }
   else {
      wait();
      int *s;
      shmid = shmget(2009, SHMSIZE, 0666 | IPC_CREAT);
      shm = shmat(shmid, 0, 0);
      s = shm;
      wait(NULL);
      printf ("Parent reads <%d>\n",shm) ;
      shmdt(shm);
      shmctl(shmid, IPC_RMID, NULL);
   }
   return 0;
}
```

And the output is just this line:

```
Enter number<1>:
```

And if I entered a number, let's say 25, it outputs this:

```
Parent reads <r>
```

*r: random -ve number changes every time I execute the code*

It never went through the child process code ! Am I doing this in a wrong way ?

Comment: Why don't you create the shared memory in the parent, and then run the child?

Comment: What is the first call to `wait` in the parent process?

Comment: Also, your argument to `scanf` is wrong.

Comment: @K-ballo That's how I was asked to do. I prefer to stick to that.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg `wait()` is to force the parent to wait for the child to finish. What is wrong with `scanf()` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My problem was so stupid. I need to provide the Child process with the ability to write into the SHM. This line in the if-block :

```
shmid = shmget(2009, SHMSIZE, 0);
```

Will become like this:

```
shmid = shmget(2009, SHMSIZE, 0666 | IPC_CREAT);
```

Thanks to you all and especially to @JoachimPileborg  :)

Comment: Accept his answer to allow both of you to hog some points. :)

Comment: I voted up for his answer. I can't accept an answer which does not solve the problem, Can I ? :)

Comment: assume code after the fork() is simultaneous and/or either one may run first.  Thus both shmget's must have the IPC_CREAT, so whomever runs first will create it.

Answer (score 14):

Ok, better collect in an answer instead...

There are several problems with you program. If you enable warnings when building (I use `-Wall -Wextra`) a lot of them will be quite evident.

The first two problems I already mentioned in my comments, but I explain them here:

1. The first is the call to `wait()`. There is no `wait` function in C or POSIX that takes no argument.
2. The second problem is the `scanf` call, you are calling it with `*++`, where `*n` takes the *value* of the memory pointed to by `n` which most likely can result in a crash. Remove the asterisk.
3. The third problem is that you treat the shared memory as both an array of integers (with `n`) and as a string. You cant really do both, pick one or the other.
4. You create the shared memory in the parent process, but wait for the child process to finish before you create the memory.
5. There is a race condition between the parent and child process, since the share memory might be created after the child tries to access it.

**Edit** I came up with this instead, which seems to work for me. I added comments on the things I changed.

```
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/ipc.h>
#include <sys/shm.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>  /* Needed for the wait function */
#include <unistd.h>    /* needed for the fork function */
#include <string.h>    /* needed for the strcat function */
#define SHMSIZE 27
int main() {
   int shmid;
   char *shm;

   if(fork() == 0) {
      shmid = shmget(2009, SHMSIZE, 0);
      shm = shmat(shmid, 0, 0);
      char *s = (char *) shm;
      *s = '\0';  /* Set first location to string terminator, for later append */
      int i;
      for(i=0; i<5; i++) {
         int n;  /* Variable to get the number into */
         printf("Enter number<%i>: ", i);
         scanf("%d", &n);

         char number[20];
         sprintf(number, "%d", n);  /* Convert the number to string */
         strcat(s, number);  /* Append the number to the string */
      }
      strcat(s, "\n");  /* Append newline */
      printf ("Child wrote <%s>\n",shm);
      shmdt(shm);
   }
   else {
      /* Variable s removed, it wasn't used */
      /* Removed first call to wait as it held up parent process */
      shmid = shmget(2009, SHMSIZE, 0666 | IPC_CREAT);
      shm = shmat(shmid, 0, 0);
      wait(NULL);
      printf ("Parent reads <%s>\n",shm) ;
      shmdt(shm);
      shmctl(shmid, IPC_RMID, NULL);
   }
   return 0;
}
```

Do note that point 5 in the list above have not been resolved.

Comment: I'll edit my code now. The main problem is that the code is working but never executing the child block, i.e the `if(fork() == 0)` block

Comment: Updated. Check it now. Still output the same with a little bit difference

Comment: @iturki Added code to my answer, containing my changes to your program.

Comment: Plus one for the dedication to fix an 11 year old bug

Answer (score 0):

Your description seems to not be correct since there is no code that outputs "Parent Wrote <>".

You are reading numbers and storing them as int in *n++, but then you are appending a '\n' character to the n-int array and you are treating shm as a string?

It seems to me that in your child you are creating a shared memory, writing to it and then closing (discarding) the shared memory. Then your second part opens a new shared memory with the same segment, but yet it is a new shared memory. Normally one process creates a shared memory, then the second opens it and when the last process closes the shared memory, then it is freed by the OS.

Comment: closing the SHM does not mean discarding it! `shmdt()` means: shared memory detatch. `shmctl()` SHM destroy. And regarding the output, it is wrong. I'll correct it.

Comment: Sorry, I am not familiar with the SHM API. But if the child process calls shmget and later terminates wouldn't linux implicitely destroy the SHM (before the parent process opens it)? And why do you IPC_CREAT on the parent, not on the child?

Comment: Child only opens and close the SHM. Then, the parent opens the same SHM, retrieve the data, close and destroy it. That's how it works.

Answer (score 0):

One problem is that the child process is attempting to use get the shared memory before it has been created by the parent.  The parent has a `wait()` call before creating the shared memory, so it won't exist when the client tries to retrieve the id. Even if the wait() call is moved, it may not work because there is a race condition.  The call to `shmget` may need to precede the `fork` call (or use some synchronization to make sure it actually exists before retrieving it in the child process).

And (as others have already pointed out), the child is attempting to write integers to the memory while the reading (printing of it) tries to treat it as a character string.