# Unexpected behavior with shared memory & forking?

Tags: c, linux, fork, shared-memory

Given the following code :

```
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/shm.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
int main()
{
    int arr[100];
    int shmid  = shmget(IPC_PRIVATE, sizeof(int), 0600);
    int *ptr = shmat(shmid, NULL, 0);
    *ptr = 42;
    arr[0] = 1;

    if (fork())
    {
        wait(NULL);
        printf("%d, %d\n",arr[0],*ptr);
    }

    else
    {
        arr[0] = 2;
        *ptr = 1337;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

The output is : `1,1337` .

Question : why it is not `2,1337` ?

How could that be if the child updates the `arr` and `ptr` is his block ? meaning , the father process updated `arr[0]` to be `1` before the `fork()` took place , then why the update of `ptr` took place and the update of `arr[0]` to value of `2` did not ?

Best regards

Comment: make sure to release the shared memory objects eventually as these will survive your program termination. See also http://stackoverflow.com/a/10685112/1025391

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`arr` is not shared between the parent and child.
After `fork`, each of them has a different copy of it. So when the child changes `arr`, it doesn't affect the parent.
Your shared memory calls affect `ptr`, but not `arr`.

Answer (score -1):

Arrays are not pointers! Array may be stored on the stack. Check assembly code.