# How to share variable in two C++ files

Tags: c++

I am trying a code which has two C++ files(`client.cpp` and `server.cpp`) and one `common.h` header file which contais a class and functions.
If client stops execution server should stop as well. For that purpose I thought of a global variable as suggested in :[How do I use extern to share variables between source files?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1433204/how-do-i-use-extern-to-share-variables-between-source-files-in-c?rq=1)
but it didn't work out for me.

Error : when I tried `g++ server.cpp common.h -o server`:

```
/tmp/ccjoNSQd.o: In function `main':
server.cpp:(.text+0x3a): undefined reference to `ch'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

client.cpp:

```
#include "common.h"

int ch=1;
int main()
{

  random r;
  do{
    cout<<"Do you want to continue: 1=yes 0=no "<<endl;
    cin>>ch;
    r.display();
    }while(ch==1);
}
```

server code:

```
#include "common.h"

int main()
{
    random r;
  do{
    cout<<"display in server"<<endl;
    r.display();
    }while(ch==1);
}
```

common.h:

```
#ifndef COMMON_H
#define COMMON_H
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
extern int ch;
class random
{
    public:
        void display()
        {
          cout<<"HELLO_WORLD"<<endl;
        } 
 }; 


#endif
```

I want to include the common.h in both the files . So according to [How do I use extern to share variables between source files?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1433204/how-do-i-use-extern-to-share-variables-between-source-files-in-c?rq=1) I've written `extern int ch` in `common.h` and used `ch` in both source files.

Comment: You're missing something that's mentioned in the accepted answer to the question you linked to... Look carefully at all the references to `global_variable` in that answer. The author of it is doing something that you're not.

Comment: I don't think this will do what you want. You can set up the source files so that there's a variable with a common name in both the client and server programs, but setting the variable in one program won't change the value of the variable in the other program.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you want will only work only in single compilation. To share variable between translation units you must move `int ch=1;` to global scope, outside any function. Then you can reference it from other translation unit if you declare it `extern int ch;`

To share some data between two different applications you must use some Inter Process Communication mechanism. The simplest one is some external file. This is a broad topic, you can find many answers on SO: [Sharing same variable between more than one independent programs in Linux](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10684499/sharing-same-variable-between-more-than-one-independent-programs-in-linux)

For platform independent solution I suggest using boost::interprocess library: http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_60_0/doc/html/interprocess/sharedmemorybetweenprocesses.html

Comment: I did edit code as you suggested but still getting same error. Can you please explain correction using some example?

Comment: hmm, you have two .cpp files and each has main - why? You want to compile two separate executables and share variable between them? You cannot do that using extern.

Comment: then can you suggest simplest solution to this with example?

Comment: No, there is no simple solution. If you have two programs you can't use a shared variable. You have to communicate between the two programs. And that is not trivial to do. You have to set up some communication process between the two.

Comment: posix_message_queues?

Comment: @Deadpool look at the boost::interprocess library link in my answer, it provides some very simple examples.

Answer (score 0):

This isn't going to work the way you think. You are compiling like this: "g++ server.cpp common.h -o server". That tells me that you are probably also compiling the client like this (or something similar): "g++ client.cpp common.h -o client".

This is going to create two separate executables. If you were compiling them into one program, you could do as the other answers suggest here: move `int ch;` into the global scope (outside of any functions, including main) of exactly one of the files, and `ch` would be shared between both files.

But you're not doing that - you're creating two *entirely separate programs.* You can't have a shared global variable between two programs. You need to use some other method of communicating such as a sockets or TCP. If they're running on the same system, you could also use a simple hack like having one process write to a text file that the other reads.

Answer (score -1):

in one and only one C file write (without `extern`) at main level (not in function)

int ch;

BUT not declare in main, beause the first will be hidden, You can set value

ch = 1;

but not declare;

Comment: can you please explain with simple example? Or modification in my code?

Comment: This question has is a very different problem.

Comment: Deadpool Your changed code has `ch` in good place. @Olaf why?

Comment: Read the question and see how it is compiled/built. Style note: Format your answers properly, e.g. code as `code`.