# fork() and changing local variables?

Tags: c, process, fork

I am trying to understand the fork() concept and there's is one thing I can't seem to understand.

In the following code - why does the parent still print i=0 even when child process changes it to 5?

The **wait(NULL)** blocks parent process until child finishes first.

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
  int i = 0;
  if (fork() == 0) {
    i = 5;
  } else {
    wait(NULL);
    printf("i = %d\n", i);
  }
  return 0;
}
```

Can somebody explain why my assumption is incorrect?

Comment: What do you imagine `fork` does?

Answer (score 6):

Variables are not shared between processes. After the call to `fork`, there are two completely separate processes. `fork` returns 0 in the child, where the local variable is set to 5. In the parent, where `fork` returns the process ID of the child, the value of `i` is not changed; it still has the value 0 set before `fork` was called. It's the same behavior as if you had two programs run separately:

```
int main(int args, char *argv[]) {
    int i=0;
    printf("i = %d\n", i);
    return 0;
}
```

and

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
  int i = 0;
  i = 5;
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: So if I wanted i=5 to print when the parent executes, how exactly could I do that without adding the statement i=5 in the parent? In short, is there a way to share variables between child and parent?

Comment: You need to pass the value to/from the child using some IPC (Inter-Process Communication) mechanism (file, pipe, socket, shared memory, ...)

Comment: Some similar topic you have [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10684499/sharing-same-variable-between-more-than-one-independent-programs-in-linux).
Yet you have to read about Inter Process Communication (IPC).

Answer (score 4):

Processes are not threads! When you fork, you create a full cloned process, with independant memory allocation that simply contains same values (except for the result of the fork call) *at the time of the fork*.

If you want a child to update some data in the parent process, you will need to use a thread. A thread shares all static and dynamic allocated memory with its parent, and simply has independant automatic variables. But even there, you should use static allocation for `i` variable:

```
int i = 0;
int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    ...
```

Answer (score 1):

When you `fork` the child process gets a copy of the address space of the parent address space, they don't share it, so when the child changed `i` the parent won't see it.

This copying of the address space it typically done using [copy on write](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Copy-on-write) to avoid allocating memory that will never change.