# How to pass a string between parent and child?

Tags: c, operating-system, shared-memory, system-calls

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<sys/ipc.h>
#include<sys/shm.h>
#include<sys/types.h>
#include<string.h>
#include<sys/stat.h>
#define SIZE 100

void main()
{
    int shmid,status;
    pid_t pid;
    int i;
    char *a,*b,d[100];
    shmid=shmget(IPC_PRIVATE,SIZE,S_IRUSR | S_IWUSR);
    pid=fork();


    if(pid==0)
    {
        b=(char *) shmat(shmid,NULL,0);
        printf("enter");
        printf("%c",*b);
        shmdt(b);
    }
    else
    {
        a=(char *) shmat(shmid,NULL,0);
        printf("enter a string");
        scanf("%s",&d);
        strcpy(a,d);
        shmdt(a);
    }
}
```

I was trying to pass a string from the parent process to the child process. But before scanning the value into "d" the program switches to the child process. How should I correct this logical error? And how should I pass this string "d" to the child process?

Comment: Why are you using shared memory? A pipe is a much better choice.

Comment: @FilipeGonçalves: As an exercise in learning about shared memory, perhaps?  This is obviously a toy program.

Answer (score 1):

After call to fork was made you never know which process will execute first. You must simply assert your code handles properly interprocess communication, whatever happens now.

You can use [pipe(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/pipe.2.html) or shared memory to pass data between different processes on same host.

```
#include <unistd.h>

int pipe(int pipefd[2]);
```

But you can also read data into global variable before call to fork. Fork will create a copy of global data in new process.

---

Shared memory using `shmget` [example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8187102/1141471).

Comment: i do not want to use pipes. i want to use shared memory .pass a string from user and child prints the string .the string should be stored in shared memory.

Comment: @rishabhagarwal attached a link to shmget example

Answer (score -1):

Fork is a system call and it creates two processes one is called the parent and the other is called the child!
To enable them to communicate you need to apply interprocess communication techniques 
You could use

```
     1.Pipes
     2.FIFO-also known as Named pipes 
     3.Shared Memory
     4.Message Queue
     5.Semaphore
```

Everything you need to know to use them is mentioned [here](http://developeriq.in/articles/2012/may/30/interprocess-communicationipc-programs-in-c-in-ubu/)!The sample codes are written after the description